# Active CSS Not Being Recognized

Tags: html, css, href

Feel like I'm missing something simple but been staring at it for too long so any help is appreciated.

Have a horizontal nav where I would like an element to have a different background color when it is active / the current page. I've tried various class tags with no success. Note that I can't just use the .active tag as I need this to function solely on the added nav.

Here's what I have and what I've tried:

CSS CODE

```
.nav2 {
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav2 li {
  Float: left;
}
.nav2 a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #666;
  font-family: Calibri,Candara,Segoe,Segoe UI,Optima,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav2 a:active {
  background-color: #0066CC;
  color: white;
}
.nav2 a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

---

ATTEMPT 1 (in LI tag-active only)

```
<ul class="nav2">
   <li class="active"><a href="one.aspx">Page One</a></li>
   <li><a href="two.aspx">Page Two</a></li>
   <li><a href="three.aspx">Page Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

ATTEMPT 2 (in A tag-active only)

```
<ul class="nav2">
   <li><a class="active" href="one.aspx">Page One</a></li>
   <li><a href="two.aspx">Page Two</a></li>
   <li><a href="three.aspx">Page Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

ATTEMPT 3 (in LI tag)

```
<ul class="nav2">
   <li class="nav2 active"><a href="one.aspx">Page One</a></li>
   <li><a href="two.aspx">Page Two</a></li>
   <li><a href="three.aspx">Page Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

ATTEMPT 4 (in A tag)

```
<ul class="nav2">
   <li><a class="nav2 active" href="one.aspx">Page One</a></li>
   <li><a href="two.aspx">Page Two</a></li>
   <li><a href="three.aspx">Page Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is your active class? :active is used if you opened that link by default link is blue and  :active is purple text colored

Comment: Thanks all! So would the format be more along these lines? .active a.nav2        - Sounds like I incorrectly assumed that .active applied to a tags automatically, but it's just a manually created class that I confused with the a:active tag.

Comment: `.active a.nav2` depends on your html, for all your 4 attempts, none of those html matches that selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a link become `:active` that user press mouse down, and when leave mouse,so remove `active`: see this(click on menu and see result):

```css
.nav2  {
 border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
 border-width: 1px 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #f3f3f3;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.nav2 li  {
 float: left;
}

.nav2 a  {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 color: #666;
 font-family: Calibri,Candara,Segoe,Segoe UI,Optima,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 }

.nav2 a:hover  {
 background-color: #555;
 color: white;
}

.nav2 a:active  {
 background-color: #0066CC;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav2">
   <li ><a class="active" href="#">Page One</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Page Two</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Page Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

in your case,you use of class `active` so you must use `.` and no `:`,like this:

```css
.nav2  {
 border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
 border-width: 1px 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #f3f3f3;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.nav2 li  {
 float: left;
}

.nav2 a  {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 color: #666;
 font-family: Calibri,Candara,Segoe,Segoe UI,Optima,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 }

.nav2 a.active  {
 background-color: #0066CC;
 color: white;
}


.nav2 a:hover  {
 background-color: #555;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav2">
   <li ><a class="active" href="#">Page One</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Page Two</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Page Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you want see `active` link, after each click,you must use of jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $('.nav2 a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
  })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a').click(function() {
  $('.nav2 a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
 })
})
```

```css
.nav2  {
 border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
 border-width: 1px 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #f3f3f3;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.nav2 li  {
 float: left;
}

.nav2 a  {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 color: #666;
 font-family: Calibri,Candara,Segoe,Segoe UI,Optima,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 }

.nav2 a.active  {
 background-color: #0066CC;
 color: white;
}


.nav2 a:hover  {
 background-color: #555;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav2">
   <li ><a class="active" href="#">Page One</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Page Two</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Page Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! Been quite some time since I've had to hand code CSS and feel silly now that I've read your replies

Answer (score 1):

You need an active class:

```
.active  {background-color: #0066CC; color: white;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.active {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav2">
   <li class="nav2"><a href="one.aspx" class="active">Page One</a></li>
   <li><a href="two.aspx">Page Two</a></li>
   <li><a href="three.aspx">Page Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Add you active class to a element otherwise it will use default styles...

Answer (score 0):

I've made this same mistake in the past after spending hours on a code. We all go through silly mistakes like this.

All markup is well, but you're just forgetting to add the '.active' class to your CSS file.

Add the following to your CSS:

```
.active { 
   background-color: #0066CC;
   color: white;  
}
```

Depending on where you place your tag, you may need to remove other options, specifically if you place in the anchor/link HTML markup. You may need to also add the following to remove the bottom line:

```
.active {
   background-color: #0066CC;
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Hope this helps!